# angular 6 check if element has a specific style

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the below `div`, when i click the first time on it i add an `opacity` style. I want to check in the same function if this `div` has an `opacity` style equal to 1

```
@ViewChild('address')
private address: ElementRef;

public onClickAddress() {
  this.renderer2.setStyle(this.address.nativeElement, 'opacity', '1');
  // check if this element has an opacity style = 1
}

<div #address (click)="onClickAddress()">

</div>
```

Comment: But why manipulate DOM manually, instead of using `ngStyle` or `ngClass`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tgua8r) you don't need `renderer2`

```
public onClickAddress() {
  this.address.nativeElement.style.opacity=1;
  if( this.address.nativeElement.style.opacity==1){
    console.log("hello")
  }
  // check if this element has an opacity style = 1
}
```